# Norm on a Quotient Space

Tags: normed-spaces, quotient-spaces

Let $E$ be  a linear space and  $F\subset E$ a subspace.
If I equip the quotient space $E/F$ with a norm, it is required that $F$ is a closed subspace. Why is that required?

Comment: Which of the properties of a norm could possibly break?

Comment: Think about $L^p$-spaces: if you view its elements as actual (measurable) functions then you need to set two such functions to be "equal" if they differ on a set of measure $0$, as otherwise the $L^p$-norm is not actually a norm: $|f|_p = 0$ requires $f(x) = 0$ off some set of measure zero and you need to consider all such $f$ as being $0$ in the space. Do you see the connection to your question if $E$ is measurable functions with finite $L^p$-norm and $F$ is some set of functions that vanish off a set of measure zero?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069082/what-is-an-example-of-infinite-dimensional-subspace-that-is-not-closed/2069084 may be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us first verify that this norm is well-defined in the case that $M \subset V$ is closed.  If $\inf_{m \in M}\|x-m\|=0$, we know that there exists a sequence of $m_i \in M$ that converges to $x$. However, since $M$ was assumed to be closed, we know that $x \in M$, which is exactly the zero vector in our quotient space.

If it were true that such an $x \notin M$ ($M$ did not contain all of its limit points), there would be some $x \neq 0$ in the quotient with norm $0$, violating the nondegeneracy axiom.