# Closed subspace

Tags: normed-spaces, quotient-spaces

If $X$ is a normed space and $Y$ is a closed subspace of $X$. I need to prove that the space form by $span(\{x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}\}\cup Y)$ is also a closed subspace of $X$. The hint given by the lecturer is that we can make use of the quotient space $X/Y$. I don't have any background on topology so I have problems dealing with this.

Below are my questions:

1. The quotient space $X/Y$ is the new space formed by identifying the elements in $Y$ am I right? Something like $D^{2}/S^{1}=S^{2}$.
2. How does the quotient space $X/Y$ help in terms of proving that $span(\{x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}\}\cup Y)$ is closed?
3. Do I have to prove by definition of closure that $span(\{x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}\}\cup Y)$ contains all the limits? Or is there an easier way?

Appreciate if anyone can explain to me how to approach this problem.

Comment: There's a fact that a vector subspace is closed if and only if the quotient is Hausdorff.

Comment: Which quotient do I prove that it is Hausdorff? $X/Y$ or $X/span$?

Comment: You would do $X/\operatorname{span}(\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n \} \cup Y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X/Y$ is endowed with the structure of a normed space such that the quotient map $p:X\rightarrow X/Y$ is continuous. $V=span(p(x_1),...,p(x_n))$ is closed since it is finite dimensional this implies that $p^{-1}(V)$ is closed.

Comment: Can you explain further how “$p^{-1}(V)$ is closed” helps in proving the question? Why is your span not including the Y?

Comment: because $p^{-1}(V)=span(Y,x_1,...,x_n)$.

Comment: May I ask one more question? How is the Y being a closed subspace a necessary condition here?

Comment: $Y$ is closed implies that $X/Y$ is endowed with a norm $\|p(x)\|=inf\|x+y\|, y\in Y$ and $p:X\rightarrow X/Y$ is continuous.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2351781/norm-on-a-quotient-space